# Python: How to generate n different copies of an object

Tags: python, copy, generator, deep-copy

I have an object with several dictionaries filled with other objects and a list of id and object pairs.

What is the most pythonic way of generating n copies of this object each time with a change applied to one of the dicts?

For Example:

```
class B(object):
    pass

class A(object):

    def __init__(self):
        d = {1: B(), 2: B(), 3: B()}


a = A()
b = [(1, B()), (2, B())]
```

I want to generate two copies of `a` each one with a different instance of B. If possible I would like to avoid using deepcopy.

**Edit:** since I was asked to be more specific:

I am running a computation n times with one parameter of a certain submodule changed each time. I would like to avoid holding n copies of the submodule in memory since it's quite a large object and I would like to avoid reinitialising other parts of the simulation. Thus I would like to have one base object, initialised, on which I would like to do n small modifications, thus running the computation n times with different parameters.

Comment: Why do you need to avoid using `deepcopy()` here? And what has `b` got to do with creating copies of `A()`?

Comment: Note that `A.d` is a **class** attribute. All instances of `A()` share that attribute, there is no copy to be made there. If `A.d` should be an instance attribute, set it in `__init__` instead.

Comment: Last but not least, `A.d`, even if it were a instance attribute, is not changed. If you wanted a new `A()` with new values for `B()`, **just create a new instance**. There is no need to use copying here.

Comment: Firstly, this is the reason I want to avoid deepcopy: https://twitter.com/gvanrossum/status/383618349000691712

Secondly, sorry for that - I fixed it now. It should be an instance attribute.

Thirdly, the reason why I don't want to make a new instance of class A is because it's a pretty big object and I want the copies to be the same except for one small change, that is update one dict elemen.

Comment: That's because whenever deepcopy is being used, the programmer gave up and took the cheap option. **There rarely is a need** to use deepcopy. Rethink the situation and ask if a deep copy of the full object hierarchy is really what is needed.

Comment: At issue is not the deep copy process itself. At issue is the need to create a copy.

Comment: I agree, that's why I posted here asking for a better solution than deepcopy-ing the object.

Comment: Then you need to be specific as to what you are doing and why you think you need a copy in the first place.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I updated the question - hopefully it's clearer now.

Comment: Why not *reuse* the object, and make the adjustments through a method on the object? Why do you need to have *copies*?

Comment: Because the simulation changes the object (which is holding state) in such a way that it would be difficult to undo the changes after each iteration.

Comment: And the variations cannot be created in the class initializer? Sounds like you don't want a copy, but a fresh object. Creating a copy takes *just as much time* to create.

Comment: They could be but it seems to me like an overkill to initialise n objects (where n could be pretty high and the initialisation is expensive) for a small change in one of the object's attributes.

Comment: Yes copying has costs *too*.

Comment: That is why I said 'I would like to **avoid** using deepcopy' or initialising the class for that matter.

Comment: So you don't want to deep copy and don't want to create a new object. Then you won't get a new object unless you create a *manual* copy function that takes care of the copying details.

Comment: If defined as ``d = {1: B(), 2: B(), 3: B()}`` inside function ``__init__`` , the object **d** is not at all a class argument of ``A`` , nor the identifier ``d`` is in the class ``A``'s namespace: it can be verified by printing ``'d' in dir(A)``. This instruction creates an object and assigns it to identifier ``d`` which becomes a local name (horridly said local variable commonly) and when the interpeter exits the function, this local name is lost vanishes because the namespace of a function is destroyed when it returns

Comment: I'm surprised by this sentence : _"I want to generate two copies of a each one with a different instance of B"_ Note that when you define ``d = {1: B(), 2: B(), 3: B()}``, the three ``B()`` are different instances, that is to say different objects. If you want two copies of ``a``, you'll have to create 6 new instances of ``B``.

Answer (score 0):

`A().d` is never changed, so there is no difference in creating a copy or creating a new instance.

So to create a new instance of `A()` that holds new, separate instances of `B()`, just create a new instance:

```
second_a = A()
```

Any variations between instances can be created directly on this new instance. If creation of such an object is expensive, use caching strategies to avoid repeated calculations.

Answer (score 0):

I think `import_fresh_module` could brings you help, according to the description of it in the doc and the description of your need. But I can't say more, not enough skilled.

Answer (score 0):

Your example isn't assigning `d` to anything, so it will be lost when `__init__` returns. But the comments suggest that you want it to be an instance attribute of `A`; I'm assuming that's what you want. I would implement a `copy` method that copies just what you want. For example, I believe this meets the criteria you have specified, at least for the example code you gave:

```
class B(object):
    pass

class A(object):

    def __init__(self, d=None):
        if d is not None:
            self.d = d
        else:
            self.d = {1: B(), 2: B(), 3: B()}

    def copy(self, updates=None):
        a = type(self)(self.d.copy())
        if updates is not None:
            a.d.update(updates)
        return a


a = A()
b = [(1, B()), (2, B())]
a2 = a.copy(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do a form of Singleton pattern here that will cache the 'expensive' bits and allow you to set the variable bits by calling it again to set different parameters:

```
class BigAssThang(object):
    instances={}
    def __new__(cls, ID, *args):
        if ID in cls.instances:
            return cls.instances[ID]
        else:
            # do somthing really big, expensive and immutable...
            cls.instances[ID]=super(BigAssThang, cls).__new__(cls)
            return cls.instances[ID]

    def __init__(self, ID, thing1=None, thing2=None, etc=None):
        # set the parameters...
        # ANY PREVIOUS INSTANCE's PARAMS ARE WIPED OUT!!!
        self.ID=ID
        self.thing1=thing1
        self.thing2=thing2
        self.etc=etc

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'id={} ID: {} thing1: {} thing2: {} etc: {}'.format(
             id(self), self.ID, self.thing1, self.thing2, self.etc)
```

To use:

```
>>> a=BigAssThang(1,'thing 1', {}, [])
>>> a.etc.append(2)
>>> a
id=4481412944 ID: 1 thing1: thing 1 thing2: {} etc: [2]
>>> b=BigAssThang(1,'thing 1', {}, [])
>>> b
id=4481412944 ID: 1 thing1: thing 1 thing2: {} etc: []
>>> a
id=4481412944 ID: 1 thing1: thing 1 thing2: {} etc: []
>>> c=BigAssThang(2,'thing 1', {'a':22}, [1,2,3])
>>> c
id=4481413072 ID: 2 thing1: thing 1 thing2: {'a': 22} etc: [1, 2, 3]
>>> b
id=4481412944 ID: 1 thing1: thing 1 thing2: {} etc: []
```

Know that once you set the parameters to `b` than they are gone for `a`. It is controlled by the `ID` argument to `__new__` -- not the Python variable name.